# Is it possible to move a Path and a Layer at the same time in Photoshop? As if they are grouped or linked

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, path

Coworker is asking to see if it is possible. He wants to move the image, but needs to keep both the Layer and the Path as one.

Comment: What is the path for?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to make that "path" a "shape layer" under the properties tab. Then to drag all the layers (including the newly created shape layer) to the new document. You will then have to click on that "shape layer" and convert it back to a path, then delete the shape layer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is this:

1. make the path
2. transform the path as a selection
3. use the selection as a layer mask (can be invisible if layer mask is
   disabled)

... at this point we have the layer with the path as a layer mask. They can move together and that's what you ask for. Then in order to get the same path at the new location, you do this:

1. Ctrl + click on the layer mask (this loads the mask as a selection) or right click on the mask and choose *Add mask to selection*
2. Go to **Paths** tab and make a path from the selecion

... at this point you get the same path at it's new location. This process allows you to move your path with the layer but in the form of a mask. It's not an issue because you can always convert masks to selections, selections to paths and paths to selections etc.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done - Click on your path and then click on the shape tool This will bring up the tool bar options.

Click on the "shape" button in the menu which will create a shape layer of your path. Then drag your image layer and new shape layer to the new .psd doc and resize and move it as requested.

Once your image is in place on the new .psd doc - go to paths and save shape as path. You can now delete the shape layer and just be left with the original path.